# iOS Implement overlay sidebar view on Main view

Tags: ios, sidebar

What you masters give some ideas on how to implement overlay sidebar view on Main view.

One perfect example is the kindle iOS app, whose side bar exactly is what I am looking for.
The purpose is that the sidebar will slide from left to right, overlay the main view, and has some transparency (by alpha) to show the home view. Say only 1/4 main view will be left on right side, and user could swipe or tap the Main view to close the side bar.

The point is main view is not moving, but let the sidebar slide in and overlay the main view, and the animation. Could you masters share some ideas, e.g. APIs I need to take a look to finish it?

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://github.com/matthewcheok/MCPanelViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent hours on this and it turned out that github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController is much closer I am looking for. It has a blur effect and overlay

Comment: https://github.com/liuxuan30/TWTSideMenuViewController had a 3D effect that is also very fancy. Consider one day i would use it

Comment: The creator of REFrostedViewController is not longer maintaining this project. Is there any alternatives out there?

Comment: I prefer to write your own